# GIM_TRIANGLE::is_point_inside wrong (bullet physics)

Tags: c++, math, 3d, bulletphysics

```
p = 0.00585938 0.117188 0

t0 = 0.477429 0.814244 0
t1 = 0.25219 0.818112 0
t2 = 0.478054 0.589852 0
```

`is_point_inside` is returning true when passed the values above. Shouldn't it return false?

Comment: I was about to suggest checking if the triangle was wound backwards, but it looks like you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just needed to lower the margin.

`tri.m_margin = 0.000001f;`